# Random variable inside object embed link

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
var a=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
//alert(a); (For testing)
</script>
<object data='http://example.com/'+a+'.php' height='100%' type='text/html' width='100%'/>
```

I want to call name of php randomly Like this. Thank you. I am new to html .
I am trying this inside blogger html editor.

Comment: __You can not concatenate `JavaScript` variables in `HTML`__ Use DOM API to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You can not concatenate `JavaScript` variables in `HTML`** Use DOM API to do so. Assign `id` attribute to the `element` and set `data` attribute.

```js
var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var obj = document.getElementById('obj');
obj.setAttribute('data', 'http://example.com/' + a + '.php');
console.log(obj.outerHTML); //To demonstrate
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<object id='obj' height='100%' type='text/html' width='100%'></object>
```

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Comment: If provided snippet works..There must be something else which is causing issue...

Comment: Yes , you did the best answer. I am trying on it and sure come to vote up you. Thank you so much . :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`DOM Api`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), like this:

```
  var generaterandom = function() {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var obj = document.createElement("object");
        obj.setAttribute("data", 'http://example.com/' + random + '.php');
        obj.setAttribute("type", 'text/html');
        obj.setAttribute("height", '100%');
        obj.setAttribute("width", '100%');
    return obj;
  }
```

you can use this method like this:

```
var ob = generaterandom()
document.write(ob.outerHTML)
```

```js
var generaterandom = function() {
  var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var obj = document.createElement("object");
      obj.setAttribute("data", 'http://example.com/' + random + '.php');
      obj.setAttribute("type", 'text/html');
      obj.setAttribute("height", '100%');
      obj.setAttribute("width", '100%');
  return obj;
}
```

```css
object {
  background:red;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="document.body.appendChild(generaterandom())" value="append" type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

what ever you are trying to accomplish here is not clear but i assume that u need to output the below HTML code into document so this is the way to do that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
</script>

  <object data='http://example.com/'<script> document.write(a);</script>'.php' height='100%' type='text/html' width='100%'/>
```

if you new and trying to learn, then keep remember to explicitly tell the browser to exact type of script he need to use like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

, not like `<script>` . becouse there is so many scripting language beside javascript.

and another thing plz don't use file names like "1.html" or "23.php" these are not valid as variable name this will make a problem in advance programming use file names that desnt break variable naming rules like "a1.php" , "a2.php" so then above code will change like

```
  <object data='http://example.com/a'+<script> document.write(a);</script>'+.php' height='100%' type='text/html' width='100%'/>
```

(concatanator - the + mark is not necessary in html)

-------------------------if you use this in blogger------------------

```
<script>
var a=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)

document.write("<object width='100%' height='100%' type='text/html' data='http://www.example.com/"+a+".php'></object>");
</script>
```

will do the trick.

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is no longer required in [HTML5 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html)

Comment: You should consider that I am trying it on blogger html editor, Not in plain html , Thank you.

Comment: yah its true but for beginners its always good habit to follow standers. so you will never miss the concepts

Comment: Please can you paste this code to blogger ?
Here is my error code . . 

Error parsing XML, line 39, column 37: Element type "object" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"